# probability that all balls are white given that two randomly drawn balls are found to be white

Tags: probability

A box contains **five** balls, two are drawn at random and are found to be **white**. If probability of all balls in urn are white is $k$ then the value of $k$ is--

I tried by letting $y$ denote the number of white balls in the urn.Then the given problem is equivalent to $$P(\text{all balls white}|\text{two balls white})P(\text{two balls white})=P(\text{two balls white}|\text{all balls white})P(\text{all balls white})$$

Now $$P(\text{two balls white})=\frac{\binom{y}2}{\binom52}$$.Also $$P(\text{two balls white}|\text{all balls white})=1$$ And $$P(\text{all balls white})=k$$
Also $$P(\text{all balls white}|\text{two balls white})=\frac{y-2}{3}$$.I cannot however figure out how to eliminate $y$ and find out $k$.I am in search of a analytical answer which uses conditional probability. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: How did you evaluate the last conditional probability?

Comment: See this related problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339782/probability-that-the-bag-contains-all-balls-white-given-that-two-balls-are-white