# A spaceship lands in your back yard. The first 5 aliens that walk out are purple. What is the probability that the next alien will be purple?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I can't find a way to solve this. Is this a Bayesian problem? This video suggests it might be Bayesian https://youtu.be/R13BD8qKeTg?t=4m34s I have no idea on how to make this quantitative.

Comment: Are you trolling or have you forgotten to include all the information?

Comment: The answer is $2$.

Comment: I have no back yard, what can I do...

Comment: This is either a joke or an introduction to the philosophical problem of induction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction . It's not a mathematical question, so will be closed here.

Comment: What shade of purple?

Comment: @mrnovice this is all the information. Is this unsolvable? I'm sorry, if it looks like I am trolling. I'm not a mathematician. After watching this video, https://youtu.be/R13BD8qKeTg?t=4m34s I suspect maybe it has a solution with Bayes theorem?

Comment: You say you've been attacking this problem for months now, so what have you achieved? Any insight? Also I think the video counts as additional information.

Comment: This is a problem similar to one treated by the mathematician Laplace, called _the sunrise problem_, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem

Comment: In retrospect, it seems the video you link gives the same info I did above.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are giving you a hard time.  It's a very valid method of inference.  It's often called the copernican principal or the mediocrity principal.  The idea is that it's most likely the purple aliens were typical so it's highly probable that it is highly probable the next will be purple.  It's possible that the aliens were a fluke and it's probable that the next alien isn't, but it's unlikely it was a fluke (though it could have been).  Unfortunately that is all I know.  I haven't studied it further.  I know people used it to predict how long the Berlin Wall would last.

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia links, all. Very interesting. 
How is this question fundamentally different from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339782/probability-that-the-bag-contains-all-balls-white-given-that-two-balls-are-white - which has an answer (which I think is incorrect)?

Comment: @mdave16 nothing, I have been painfully clueless

Comment: While it is tempting to put the problem statement only in the title (and use the body of your Question only for some "editorial" remarks), it is best to use the body of the Question to include a full statement of your problem.  In this case Readers are not sure whether you've simply omitted relevant information to make the problem fit into the title or not.  I appreciate that in the Comments you claim this is not so, but I offer it as one advantage (and there are others) to use the body of the Question for a complete problem setup and discussion of context.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using experimental probability, the probability is 1. If it is theoretical probability, then I don't see a way to find it. Is this a joke?

Comment: Not a joke, I have struggled to find a way to attack this problem for many months now. Is this unsolvable?

Comment: "If you're using experimental probability, the probability is 1" Hmmm... which *experience(s)* could you be alluding to here?